# I am confused why my fillDeck function says, "assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'const char *"

Tags: c++, pointers

When I try to fill my Card deck with card structures of the face value and suit I get the error that is above. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#define CARDS 52
#define FACES 13
#define SUITS 4
using namespace std;

typedef struct card
{
    char * face;
    char * suit;
}Card;
 void fillDeck(Card * const wDeck, const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[]);
 void shuffle(Card * const wDeck);
 void deal(const Card * const wDeck);

int main(void)
{
    Card deck [CARDS];
    const char * face[] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
            "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten",
            "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    const char * suit[] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
    srand(time(NULL));
    fillDeck(deck, face, suit);
    shuffle(deck);
    deal(deck);
}
void fillDeck(Card * wDeck, const char * wFace[], const char * wSuit[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i< CARDS; i++)
    {
        wDeck[i].face = wFace[i % FACES];
        wDeck[i].suit = wSuit[i / FACES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
wDeck[i].face = wFace[i % FACES];
```

Pop quiz:

Q: What is `wDeck`?

A: It's a `Card` class instance.

Q: What is it's "face" member?

A: It's a `char *`.

Q: What's in the `WFace` array?

A: `const char *`s.

Q: Why, in C++, can't you assign a pointer to a constant object, to a pointer to a mutable (non-constant) object?

A: Because a constant object is, well, constant. But if you have a pointer to it, and you copy that pointer to a different mutable pointer, it means that you could modify the constant value using the different, mutable pointer.

Now, how about you now try to answer your own question?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign a `const char*` to a `char*` variable. This happens because you declared `Card` as

```
typedef struct card
{
    char* face; // <- non const char*
    char* suit; // <- non const char*
} Card;
```

and declared `wDeck` as

```
Card * wDeck // <- non const Card*
```

and declared `wFace` as

```
const char * wFace[] // <- const char*
```

When you try to assign

```
wDeck[i].face = wFace[i % FACES];
```

`wDeck` and `face` are not `const`, but `wFace` contains `const char *` pointers, so you are assigning a `const char*` to a non-const `char*` field of a non-const `struct`.  You cannot assign a const pointer to a non-const pointer.

In addition, this code looks like much more C than C++:

- You don't need `typedef struct card`, `struct Card` is enough;
- You should use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of plain C arrays.

Finally I don't see the point of using strings to reference a specific card, this is not conceptually correct. A better approach would be something like:

```
enum class Face {
 ACE,
 TWO,
 ...
};

enum class Suit {
 HEARTS,
 CLUBS,
 ..
}

class Card {
private:
  const Face face;
  const Suit suit;
public:
  Card(Face face, Suit suit) : face(face), suit(suit) { }
  std::string getName() const { ... }
};
```

If you want to use C++ then try to make use of its features, otherwise it makes no sense to use C++ at all.